# Édouard - Эдуар или Эдуард?

Tags: ономастика, заимствования, переводы

Как правильно по-русски звучит имя нового премьер-министра Франции: ***Эдуар*** *Филипп*, без "д" на конце, или все-таки ***Эдуард*** *Филипп*, с использованием русского эквивалента имени?

Как и новый французский премьер, это имя носил, например, художник-импрессионист Мане, которого мы называем Эдуардом, а не Эдуаром. И у Мане, и у Филиппа имена по-французски пишутся одинаково - Édouard Manet и Édouard Philippe. Логично и по-русски называть их одинаково. Только надо определиться - именовать новоиспеченного главу правительства Эдуардом или переименовывать Мане и всех остальных французов, носивших это имя.

Answer (score 1):

> Эдуа́р Фили́пп (фр. Édouard Philippe, род. 28 ноября 1970, Руан) —
>   французский политик, депутат Национального собрания Франции, мэр
>   города Гавр, премьер-министр Франции с 15 мая 2017 года.

**[источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BF%2C_%D0%AD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%80)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Повод улыбнуться.

В речи, скорее всего, он будет Эдуардом - цензуры-то нынче нет... Но вполне возможно, что СМИ будут переданы ЦУ.

> **фр. Édouard — Эдуа́р(д)**

**[источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4)**

Так что варианты допускаются.

---

Довесок [про Мане](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5,_%D0%AD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4):

> Эдуа́рд (Эдуа́р) Мане́ (фр. Édouard Manet [edwaʁ manɛ]; 23 января
>   1832, Париж — 30 апреля 1883, Париж) — французский живописец, гравёр,
>   один из родоначальников импрессионизма.

Answer (score 0):

Имя Эдуард во Франции произносится как Эдуар. Поскольку Эдуар Мане был французским художником, поэтому называть его надо именно Эдуар, а не на английский манер Эдуард. Также правомочно Робер, а не Роберт.

Comment: Но ведь нет такого правила, чтобы в русском полностью повторять произношение языка-источника.

Comment: На Ленинском на нечётной стороне есть магазин «Беларуский трыкатаж». Правомочно? Да только в качестве некой экзотики.